# setText() method resetting after user exits activity

Tags: android, android-layout, button, android-button, settext

So when the user clicks the button i want it to set the text to a future time. It works but when the user closes the activity the buttons reset. Also if someone could also guide me on creating a method that resets the button text after time is reached. Heres my code to setText on the button.

```
private void setReloadTime(int reload, Button btn) {
    int minutes = (reload/1000/60)%60;
    int hours = reload/1000/60/60;

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int min = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int hr = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    if (reload ==0){
        btn.setTextColor(R.color.colorAccent);
        btn.setText("Ready Again In 24 Hours");
        return;

    }
    if (minutes+min>60) hr++;
    int finMin = (minutes + min) %60;
    int finHr= (hours + hr)%24;
    String fin = "Ready again at " +finHr + ":";
    if (finMin<10){
        fin = fin +"0"+finMin;
    } else{
        fin = fin + finMin;
    }
    btn.setTextColor(R.color.colorAccent);
    btn.setText(fin);


}
```

Comment: guidlines is follow the answers that will be given, research more, actually the real guidline is, your activity controls whatever is in on the screen, so when its gone everything on the screen is gone, save your time using the sharedpreference style provided by the two answers, along with the text, the next time your activity comes up retrieve it, and check it with the current time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `shared preference`

Eg:

```
public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;
   SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

  Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(Name, fin);
    editor.commit(); 
     if (sharedpreferences.contains(Name))
          {

     btn.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(Name, ""));

          }
```

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm

Answer (score 1):

You should save that state of your application (Button, time etc) in SharedPreferences. On Reloading activity read from that